Pandas deeply nested json object, how to get parent nested with json_normaliza
`Im trying to read an nested api. The record nodes is nested in level 3, and I need a subvalue of to the parent.
When reading the parent I get the object, but reading a sub key it returns a Key error:
JSON object:
data={ 'results': 
                    [
                        {
                            'id':1,
                            "x": [{
                                "state": "Florida",
                                "shortname": "FL",
                                "info": {"governor": "Rick Scott"},
                                "counties": [
                                    {"name": "Dade", "population": 12345},
                                    {"name": "Broward", "population": 40000},
                                    {"name": "Palm Beach", "population": 60000},
                                ],
                            },
                            {
                                "state": "Ohio",
                                "shortname": "OH",
                                "info": {"governor": "John Kasich"},
                                "counties": [
                                    {"name": "Summit", "population": 1234},
                                    {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337},
                                ],
                            }],
                            "Y":
                                {'TEST':1}
                        },
                        {  
                            'id':2,
                            "x":[{
                                "state": "Ohio",
                                "shortname": "OH",
                                "info": {"governor": "John Kasich"},
                                "counties": [
                                    {"name": "Summit", "population": 1234},
                                    {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337},
                                ],
                            }],
                            "Y":
                                {'TEST':1}
                        }
                     
                ]
            }

Json normalize call, which gives error: KeyError: "Key 'TEST' not found. To replace missing values of 'TEST' with np.nan, pass in errors='ignore'"
result = pd.json_normalize(
           record_path=data["results"], 
           meta=['x', "counties"][["x", "state"], ["x", "info", "governor"], "Y", ["Y", "TEST"]],

            )

With error = "ignore" the following dataframe is returned.
        name  population  x.state x.info.governor            Y Y.TEST

0        Dade       12345  Florida      Rick Scott  {'TEST': 1}    NaN
1     Broward       40000  Florida      Rick Scott  {'TEST': 1}    NaN
2  Palm Beach       60000  Florida      Rick Scott  {'TEST': 1}    NaN
3      Summit        1234     Ohio     John Kasich  {'TEST': 1}    NaN
4    Cuyahoga        1337     Ohio     John Kasich  {'TEST': 1}    NaN
5      Summit        1234     Ohio     John Kasich  {'TEST': 1}    NaN
6    Cuyahoga        1337     Ohio     John Kasich  {'TEST': 1}    NaN


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, so what do you want to ask? For example, do you want to ask why you're getting the error, or how to fix it? or both? Check out [ask] then [edit] to clarify. Secondly, if you're looking for a solution, what's the desired output? Please include that too. For reference see [mre] and How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Pardon me, I didn't notice you put a question in the title, "how to get parent nested with json_normaliz[e]". I might have missed it because you didn't write a question mark.

You'll need to do 2 levels to flatten it.
import pandas as pd

data={ 'results': 
                    [
                        {
                            'id':1,
                            "x": [{
                                "state": "Florida",
                                "shortname": "FL",
                                "info": {"governor": "Rick Scott"},
                                "counties": [
                                    {"name": "Dade", "population": 12345},
                                    {"name": "Broward", "population": 40000},
                                    {"name": "Palm Beach", "population": 60000},
                                ],
                            },
                            {
                                "state": "Ohio",
                                "shortname": "OH",
                                "info": {"governor": "John Kasich"},
                                "counties": [
                                    {"name": "Summit", "population": 1234},
                                    {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337},
                                ],
                            }],
                            "Y":
                                {'TEST':1}
                        },
                        {  
                            'id':2,
                            "x":[{
                                "state": "Ohio",
                                "shortname": "OH",
                                "info": {"governor": "John Kasich"},
                                "counties": [
                                    {"name": "Summit", "population": 1234},
                                    {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337},
                                ],
                            }],
                            "Y":
                                {'TEST':1}
                        }
                     
                ]
            }
    

# Flatten 'x' with correct meta paths
x_flattened = pd.json_normalize(
    data,
    record_path=['results', 'x'],
    meta=[['results', 'id'], ['results', 'Y', 'TEST']],
    meta_prefix='meta_'
)

# Flatten 'counties' within each 'x' entry
counties_flattened_list = []
for idx, row in x_flattened.iterrows():
    counties_flattened = pd.json_normalize(row['counties'])
    counties_flattened['state'] = row['state']
    counties_flattened['shortname'] = row['shortname']
    counties_flattened['governor'] = row['info.governor']
    counties_flattened['meta_results.id'] = row['meta_results.id']
    counties_flattened['meta_results.Y.TEST'] = row['meta_results.Y.TEST']
    counties_flattened_list.append(counties_flattened)

counties_flattened = pd.concat(counties_flattened_list, ignore_index=True)

Alternate:
y_result = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,   
    record_path=['results'],
)



counties_result = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    record_path=['results', 'x', 'counties'],
    meta=[
        ['results', 'id'], 
        ['results', 'x', 'state'], 
        ['results', 'x', 'shortname'], 
        ['results', 'x', 'info', 'governor']
        ],
)


result = pd.merge(counties_result, y_result, how='outer', left_on='results.id', right_on='id')

Output:
print(counties_flattened.to_string())
         name  population    state shortname     governor  meta_results.id  meta_results.Y.TEST
0        Dade       12345  Florida        FL   Rick Scott                1                    1
1     Broward       40000  Florida        FL   Rick Scott                1                    1
2  Palm Beach       60000  Florida        FL   Rick Scott                1                    1
3      Summit        1234     Ohio        OH  John Kasich                1                    1
4    Cuyahoga        1337     Ohio        OH  John Kasich                1                    1
5      Summit        1234     Ohio        OH  John Kasich                2                    1
6    Cuyahoga        1337     Ohio        OH  John Kasich                2                    1

